# Relative directory not working on subdomain - adding subdomain to src

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

I've got a blog I installed to my /blog directory and have the htaccess written so that it only displays if you go to http://blog.domain.com

So my hierarchy looks like this

```
/blog
/system
    /js
    /css
    <php pages>
```

I have a header file that is included that has all the links to my style sheets and javascript files. On http://domain.com when they are included it will look like this instead and I can't figure out why.

```
 <link href="../system/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Which works great but when I try to call this from my /blog directory it shows up like this

```
  <link href="http://blog.domain.com/system/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Which obviously doesn't exist.  The code is the same, it should be a relative path to the css directory. What am I missing here?